# Multiple select to function like radio in a group

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, multiple-select

I need to select only 1 option inside a group. I have used multiple-select.js

I should be able to click either

A1 OR A2 OR A3

AND

B1 OR B2 OR B3

I also tried with -   thought that it can deselect previous buttons when a new one is clicked as long as all of them have the same name but in vain.

```html
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/multiple-select/1.2.0/multiple-select.min.js"></script>
      
          <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/multiple-select/1.2.0/multiple-select.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        
        
    </head>
    <body>
        <select multiple="multiple">
            <optgroup label="Group A">
                <option value="1">Radio A1</option>
                <option value="2">Radio A2</option>
                <option value="3">Radio A3</option>            
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="Group B">
                <option value="4">Radio B1</option>
                <option value="5">Radio B2</option>
                <option value="6">Radio B3</option>   
            </optgroup>
        </select>
        <script>
            $('select').multipleSelect(
            {
                multiple: true,
                multipleWidth: 300,
            selectAll: false,
                width: '100%',
                
                onClick: function(view) {
                    //;
                }            
            }
            
            );
        </script>
    </body>
```

Comment: I have created some similar compact specialized controls for mobile devices in the past, but have never found plugins that offer this type of behavior. It typically requires custom CSS and JavaScript or equivalent to implement the conditional switching and display functionality. I assume that you want the drop-down to stay open until two choices are made?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally,multiple-select plugin does not support your desired behavior where you can choose only one choice in each optgroup in a single select.However,you can choose only one choice in a single select without optgroup.

So you can use 2 "single row" selects to accomplish your desired functionality.

PS: I have tried to customize the multiple-select behavior enabling you to choose only one radio button in a single optgroup,but the plugin is not flexible enough.

```html
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/multiple-select/1.2.0/multiple-select.css" />
</head>

<body>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Choose Group A and B</legend>
        <label>Group A</label>
        <select multiple="multiple">
            <option value="1">Radio A1</option>
            <option value="2">Radio A2</option>
            <option value="3">Radio A3</option>
        </select>

        <label>Group B</label>
        <select multiple="multiple">
            <option value="4">Radio B1</option>
            <option value="5">Radio B2</option>
            <option value="6">Radio B3</option>
        </select>
    </fieldset>


    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/multiple-select/1.2.0/multiple-select.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $('select').multipleSelect({
            multiple: true,
            multipleWidth: 300,
            selectAll: false,
            width: '100%',
            single: true,
            onClick: function (view) {
                /*
                view.label: the text of the checkbox item
                view.checked: the checked of the checkbox item
                */
                //Uncheck other checkboxes in the group
            },
            onOptgroupClick: function (view) {
                /*
                view.label: the text of the optgroup
                view.checked: the checked of the optgroup
                view.children: an array of the checkboxes (DOM elements) inside the optgroup
                */
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Hope it can help you.

For the sake of space in a form ,use bootstrap inline form:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Multiple select to function like radio in a group</title>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <style>

    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <form class="form-inline">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Choose Group A and B</legend>
                <label>Group A </label>
                <select class="form-control">
                    <option value="1">Radio A1</option>
                    <option value="2">Radio A2</option>
                    <option value="3">Radio A3</option>
                </select>

                <label>Group B </label>
                <select class="form-control">
                    <option value="4">Radio B1</option>
                    <option value="5">Radio B2</option>
                    <option value="6">Radio B3</option>
                </select>
            </fieldset>

        </form>
    </div>

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks yinchaoonline, would have been much great if it was in a single dropdown. I have no space in my form. If you could help please...

Comment: I am not familiar with the plugin,if for the sake of space in a form,you can use inline form with bootstrap.